# Coset representatives form a group....sometimes?

Tags: group-theory

I am reading “Lie Groups and Lie Algebras and some of Their Applications” by Robert Gilmore and I have become hopelessly confused over what I am sure is a simple matter.  With $H$ a normal subgroup of the group $G$ Gilmore writes:

“A right coset is the set of group operations $c_0$, $c_1$, ... $\in G$ with the property that $H c_0 + H c_1 + ... = G$ and, furthermore, no element $g$ of $G$ is contained more than once in the sum on the left.”

First, is this a non-standard definition of a “coset”? I recall learning that *a coset* (not “the coset”) was a set of the form $Hg$ and that what Gilmore is describing is called a “transversal” of the cosets or a collection of “coset representatives.” He goes on to provide the following theorem:

“If $H$ is an invariant subgroup of $G$ then the coset elements $c_0$, $c_1$, $c_2$, ... can be chosen in such a way that they are closed under multiplication and form a group called the *factor group* $G/H$”

So it seems to me that under Gilmore’s definition we speak of “the coset” of a group $G$ with normal subgroup $H$ instead of “the cosets” which, the way I recall learning it, are several sets that partition $G$ and which are each elements of the factor group. Furthermore I tried to find a multiplicatively closed collection $c_i$ for $D_4$ (dihedral group of order 8 - the symmetries of a square) with $H=\{I, R_{180}\}$ and I can’t do it. I was able to do it for $A_4$ with $H=\{(1), (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$. Am I just confusing myself somehow?

Gilmore later asks the reader to prove that a collection of coset representatives can always be chosen in such a way that they form the same group as $G/H$ when $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Can someone give me a hint about how to do that proof and maybe demonstrate this for $D_4$?

Comment: His treatment sounds eccentric, to say the least.

Comment: I couldn't believe it so I checked, but this is really written. Use another book, there are many serious ones.

Comment: So....am I right that this is not possible for $D_4$? Is the theorem even correct? Is it correct always or just under certain circumstances. Isn’t the theorem equivalent to, “We can always find a transversal associated with the cosets of a normal subgroup such that the transversal is itself a group?”

Comment: I think you are right. It would follow that every quotient of a group is isomorphic to a subgroup.

Comment: Thank you YCor and Berci for your comments. I think I just need to accept that the book has a pretty basic error. I have answered my own question (see answer) and noted that Gilmore actually said what Berci said in a second book!

Comment: I think I figured this out! What Gilmore writes is true for _continuous_ groups! I think I have demonstrated for myself that this proposition is true for continuous groups when the invariant subgroup is the simply connected region containing the identity. I still can’t find any references that illuminate this idea and Gilmore does not prove it in the text, but I think the statement is true for continuous groups.